# 4G modem, address and connected but no interface?

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager

I have my 4G serria device configured and it automatically connects and gets an IP address no issue.

However for some reason network-manager is not automatically assigning the IP address to the appropriate interface.

How do I get my system to take the IP from the 4G GSM modem automatically on boot/connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the problem here was that it was asking for the interface name while configuring the device, this was where I made my mistake. in the config file I put wwan1 (the name of the device as given by linux).

The issue was that, cdc-wdm2, was the correct device name...

By going running `mmcli -m 0` I was able to see a range of device names under "system -> ports" wwan1 was there wwan1(net) but what I needed was cdc-wdm2(qmi)

```
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/TRIMMED
           |              drivers: qcserial, qmi_wwan
           |               plugin: Sierra
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm2
           |                ports: wwan1 (net), cdc-wdm2 (qmi), ttyUSB2 (at), wwan0 (net), 
           |                       cdc-wdm1 (qmi), ttyUSB1 (gps), ttyUSB0 (qcdm)
```

Comment: How you added "cdc-wdm2" to it?